# CSS: Right menu is coming over the footer

Tags: css, menu

I made a simple website CSS design, the right menu is coming over the footer menu

http://jsfiddle.net/aburayane/ppkdM

```
 .content{
    border: 10px solid red;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 700px;
}

.menuRight{
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #CC00CC;
    border: 1px solid green;

}
```

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `overflow: hidden` on the `.content` selector.

```
.content{
    border: 10px solid red;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 700px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Great, if my answer helped you, or someone else's answer helped you better, please mark the best answer as answered.

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: the cars + the description should be at the center, each car has its own description, it should just below it

Comment: What do you mean they should be at the center? This looks like a completely different problem from the one you posed in your question.

Comment: I resume it is the same, floating issue, I can see three added classes (cars, car-list and .car-list:after), now it is centered :)

Comment: It wasn't the same floating issue: after the other example was solved, you came with a different example where you asked for a floating list to be centered, and for a list of descriptions below the other floating list to match. It *is* a different issue. Just because it had to do with floats too doesn't mean that they are the same issue.

Comment: thanks man, I understood that was a floating issue, because it was floating, so that it cannot be centered

Answer (score 2):

To clear the right menu you may set `clear:both` in footer.

http://jsfiddle.net/ppkdM/1/

Answer (score 2):

Because your right menu is floating, you need to add a [clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).

Try adding this to the `content` div:

```
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

working example :
http://jsfiddle.net/agconti/ppkdM/2/

This is the best practice way to do it. You can add this class to any element that you're floating to solve similar issues in the future. Additionally the link above will tell you all you need to know about it.

If you use `overflow: hidden` you'll end up hiding some of the content from your menu, which is baadd mmm'kay.

Answer (score 2):

You can either set the **max-height: ??px;** of .menuRight in CSS, you can set the **overflow: hidden;** of .content in CSS or you can set the z-indexes of each class in CSS in order to decide which div shows above each other div.

Comment: I tried the min-height, but I should set .content to overflow: hidden to get it work

Comment: Sorry, it should have read **max-height: ??px;** either way, I'm glad that you got it sorted out. Keep rocking man

Comment: max-height will hide some menu contents, so will not work @ 100%, thanks dude, cheers

Answer (score 2):

there are another  tips to finish what you want to do. it is negative margin. 
you want  Two columns of the same height.we can do something as follow:

```
 <div class="content" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="content-wrap" style="padding-top: 9999px; margin-top: -9999px;">
        <div class="col1"></div>
        <div class="col2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

check the code at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RJKt2/1/)

haha..sorry, maybe you want to clear float.we can do this easily as follow:

```
 .content:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      clear: both;
 }
```